# Wie sagt man: "I didn't mean to ruin your weekend, though" auf Deutsch

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Wie sagt man: "I didn't mean to ruin your weekend, though" auf Deutsch?

Like, informally, to a friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the verb *versauen*. Other options are *vermiesen* and *verderben*.

> Ich wollte dir nicht das Wochenende versauen.

Comment: To include the `though` I'd say "Ich wollte dir aber nicht das Wochenende versauen/vermiesen"